# Elasticsearch shard allocation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 1 ES cluster with 3 nodes, 1 index, 3 shards and 2 replica per shard.

For some reason, all my primary shards are located on the same node:

- Node 1: replica 0, replica 1, replica 2
- Node 2: replica 0, replica 1, replica 2
- Node 3: primary 0, primary 1, primary 2.

What I should do to rebalance shards? I want to have 1 primary shard per 1 node, for example:

- Node 1: primary 0, replica 1, replica 2
- Node 2: replica 0, primary 1, replica 2
- Node 3: replica 0, replica 1, primary 2.

Comment: could you try a 3 shard and 1 replica per shard combination?

Comment: yes, but I want to have 2 replica per shard, my 3 nodes should allow to do that. My question is how can I swap replica and primary shard betwween nodes?